# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/appff.scss. Laravel:10.6.2, while installing new project with php artisan auth:ui

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-vite

Why i  have this error when i try to run my app in pro mode with laravel 10 while in dev mode it run perfectly:

> Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/appff.scss. Laravel:10.6.2, while installing new project with php artisan auth:ui.